# Using SSHFS with launchd

Tags: macos, filesystem, launchd, mount

I have a Raspberry Pi I want to automount on my Desktop (Yosemite 10.10.1).  I've installed OSXFuse (with the MacFuse option) and SSHFS both from https://osxfuse.github.io/.  I'm using the password method for now and will establish certificates after I get this problem solved.

The following command works fine from Terminal:

```
/bin/mkdir /Volumes/RaspPi ; echo "mypassword" | /usr/local/bin/sshfs myuserid@192.168.8.16:/ /Volumes/RaspPi -o workaround=rename -o password_stdin -o allow_other -o defer_permissions -ovolname=RaspPi
```

Placing it into a launchd plist worked the first day.  The volume would get mounted and if I ejected it, launchd would remount it.  But subsequently it has failed with the error:

```
kernel[0]: OSXFUSE: user-space initialization failed (4)
```

The RaspPi mountpoint gets created in /Volumes, but the volume doesn't get mounted.

The plist contains these lines:

```
    <string>bash</string>
    <string>-c</string>
    <string>/bin/mkdir /Volumes/RaspPi ; echo "mypassword" | /usr/local/bin/sshfs myuserid@192.168.8.16:/ /Volumes/RaspPi -o workaround=rename -o password_stdin -o allow_other -o defer_permissions -ovolname=RaspPi</string>
```

I reviewed a lot of discussion about OSXFuse working via Terminal and not in launchd, but none of the solutions dealt with "initialization failed (4)".  They all seemed to deal with a socket problem and error 57.  I tried a few of those solutions, but they did not help.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I got it fixed by adding

```
<key>AbandonProcessGroup</key>
<true/>
```

More info about it can be found here [OSX run script to mount sshfs at login with a plist file](http://serverquestions.com/questions/bpgi/osx-run-script-to-mount-sshfs-at-login-with-a-plist-file)

Comment: I spent an hour yesterday debugging a sshfs plist I wrote. Adding this fixed it! Thanks!